# OS X - drag file onto executable to launch with file as first argument?

Tags: macos, executable

I have Mono application which takes a file as the only argument. For example if I invoked the application with a file named "MyFile.txt" it would be done like so:

```
Mono app.exe MyFile.txt
```

In Windows I can simply drag a file onto an executable to run it with that file as an argument. Can I do the same thing in OS X?

You cant simply drag one file onto another by default, so there must be another way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use Automator to make an application, which will treat any files dropped on it as an input. A "Run Shell Script" action will let you run the `mono app.exe` on the files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at my Mac right now, but I don't believe you can drag a file onto your app because the exe would not be considered by OS X to be an application.

Instead you would wrap the exe into a Mac .app that bundled/called Mono. I assume you can do this with MonoMac.